# Infinite product of the form $2-2^{1/k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

How can I show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{k=2}^{n} (2-2^{1/k})=0$$ This is an exercise from a college admission exam, and the answer is given as 0.
 I don't understand how infinitely many positive numbers can have a product equal to $0$.
 I tried to take the logarithm of the product and use the fact that $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1$$ and get rid of it, but I am left with $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} (1-2^{1/k})$$ Is it correct? Any other approaches would be appreciated.

Comment: Notice that if you multiply these quantities together for incrementing $k$ that it gets closer to zero.

Comment: Well, if i go into my calculator, I get these results. $$\left(2-2^{1/2}\right)=0.58; \\ \left(2-2^{1/2}\right)\left(2-2^{1/3}\right)=0.433$$. Thus, as we multiply more terms (i.e. as $n\to\infty$), the product goes to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $1+x\leq e^x$, we have that

$$1+\frac{\ln 2}{k} \leq 2^{1/k}$$

$$1-\frac{1}{2k}\geq 1-\frac{\ln 2}{k} \geq 2-2^{1/k}.$$

So, it suffices to prove that the infinite product

$$\prod_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{2k-1}{2k}$$

tends to $0$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: using the fact that $$\prod_{k=2}^{n} \frac{2k-1}{2k} < \frac{2}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$$ Are there other easier ways?

Comment: @Zacky Stirling's approximation also works. I believe you could also take logs, use $\log(1+x)\leq x$ again (or something similar in the other direction) and use that the harmonic series diverges, but I haven't gone through the details on that.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it is equivalent to prove that $\sum_{k=2}^\infty (1-2^{1/k})=-\infty$. You can find a general statement about logarithms of infinite products at [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_Infinite_Product_of_Real_Numbers)

To conclude, use the Mean value theorem to have $2^\alpha-1 = 2^\alpha-2^0 \geq \log 2 \cdot \alpha$ for $\alpha \geq 0$. This shows that our series goes to infinity at least as fast as the harmonic series.