# Limit of a product of numbers from unit interval

Tags: real-analysis

Compute the limit of
$$
\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(  2-\sqrt[k]{2}\right)  ,
$$
when $n$ goes to infinity.
I tried to use ratio test for sequence or to obtain an upper bound for the expresion above which is less than $1$, then, using the squeeze theorem  to obtain something. Thank you very much for any idea.

Comment: Take the logarithm and recall $2^{1/k}=1+\frac{\ln{2}}{k}+O(k^{-2})$.

Comment: Has been asked before so more answers can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2657501/infinite-product-of-the-form-2-21-k)

Answer (score 1):

$\sum (2^{\frac 1 k} -1)= \infty$. To see this note that $2^{\frac 1 k}=e^{\frac 1 k \ln \, 2}=1+\frac 1 k \ln \, 2+o(\frac 1 k)$. It follows that $\sum \ln (2-2^{\frac 1 k})=-\infty$ because $\frac {\ln (1-x)} {-x} \to 1$ as $x \to 0$. Taking exponential we see that the given infinte product has the value $0$.

Comment: Uh, shouldn't the infinite product be $0$?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Thanks. I made a stupid mistake. All the partial products are in fact in $(0,1)$!